# Grails: NonUniqueObjectException with new session

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using the following code in a grails application:

```
def domainId = params.id
def domain = Domain.get(domainId)
def users = // assume this is an array of approx 2200 entries
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    void run() {
        User.withNewSession {
            def mDomain = Domain.get(domainId)
            users.each { user ->
                try {
                    // some code
                    mDomain.save(flush:true)
                } catch (e) {
                    log.error(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
t.start()
```

The above code gives the exception - `NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`

The exception doesn't come for all the entries in array. Out of 2200 entries, the exception was thrown for around 1500. I am already using `withNewSession` in the new thread and for all the entries in `users` array, same instance of `mDomain` is used.

Comment: A typo in `flush:true`..

Comment: sorry for that. I have updates it in the question. It's not there in original code